# Symfony2 form and Doctrine2 - update foreign key in assigned entities fails

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have profiles and studies. One person can finish many studies. The form renders correctly. There is a button "Add new study" and with jQuery I add another subform based on data-prototype and this works well. When I submit such a form with new subforms I get an database error

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'profile_id' cannot be null
```

I understand this error but I don't know how to get rid of it. I know I can update collection of studies after binding in controller but I hope there is a way to configure it properly in annotations. When I only update entities everything works fine.

The code is:

```
class Profile {
    /**
     * @var integer $profileId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="profile_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $profileId;
...
    /**
     *
     * @var Study
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Study", mappedBy="profile", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $study;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->study = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
...
}
```

and

```
    class Study {
    /**
     * @var integer $studyId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="study_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $studyId;
...
    /**
     * @var Profile
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Profile")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="profile_id", referencedColumnName="profile_id")
     * })
     */
    private $profile;
...
}
```

with s(g)etters. Underlaying database structure is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profile` (
  `profile_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`profile_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `study` (
  `study_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `profile_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`study_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `study`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `study_fk2` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id`) REFERENCES `profile` (`profile_id`);
```

Form buidlers are:

```
class ProfileType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('study', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new StudyType(),
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true
                        )
                )
    }
...
}
```

and

```
class StudyType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('city') //example field not included in above structures
    }
...
}
```

The Javascript part

```
function profileNewStudy() {
    var nr = $('[class^=profile_study_][class*=type2]').last().parent();
    nr = nr.attr('id').split('_');
    nr = nr.pop()*1 + 1;
    var proto = $('#profile_study').data('prototype');
    proto = proto.replace(/\$\$name\$\$/g, nr);
    $('#profile_study').append(proto).find('.profile_study_' + nr + ' input').val('qpa' + nr);
}
```

and Twig template

```
<form action="#" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Zapisz"/>
</form>
```

For testing purposes I removed from database constraint NOT NULL on study.profile_id and then everything was saved except that study.profile_id=null.

**edited after @Gremo answer**

I did some tests. Unfortunately it didn't help :( I corrected his mistakes with code

```
class Profile
    /**
     * @var Study
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Study", mappedBy="profile")
     */
    private $study;
class Study
    /**
     * @var Profile
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Profile", inversedBy="study")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE", referencedColumnName="profile_id")
     */
    private $profile;
```

and when I added new Study entity in form and posted it to server I got an error: A new entity was found through the relationship 'Alden\xxxBundle\Entity\Profile#study' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: Alden\xxxBundle\Entity\Study@0000000073eb1a8b00000000198469ff. Explicitly persist the new entity or configure cascading persist operations on the relationship. If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'Alden\xxxxBundle\Entity\Study#__toString()' to get a clue.

So I added cascade to profile:

```
/**
 * @var Study
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Study", mappedBy="profile", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $study;
```

and than I got an error like in the begining: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'profile_id' cannot be null.

**edited**
My controller code:

```
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $r = $this->getProfileRepository();
    $profile = $id ? $r->find($id) : new \Alden\BonBundle\Entity\Profile();
    /* @var $profile \Alden\BonBundle\Entity\Profile */
    $form = $this->createForm(new ProfileType(), $profile);
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $vacation = $profile->getVacation();
            foreach($vacation as $v) {
                $r=5;
            }
            $em = $this->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($profile);
            $em->flush();
            //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('profile_list'));
        }
    }
    return array(
        'profile' => $profile,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    );
```

**SOLUTION**

In Profile class, important parts are cascade, orphanRemoval in annotations and foreach loop in setStudies() (thanks to suggestion @Parhs)

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Study", mappedBy="profile", cascade={"ALL"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $studies;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->studies = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getStudies()
{
    return $this->studies;
}

public function setStudies($studies)
{
    foreach ($studies as $v)
    {
        if (is_null($v->getProfile()))
        {
            $v->setProfile($this);
        }
    }
    $this->studies = $studies;
}
```

In Study class

```
/**
 * @var Profile
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Profile", inversedBy="studies")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="profile_id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE", referencedColumnName="profile_id")
 */
private $profile;
```

and usual getters and setters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand you correctly your relation is bidirectional, so you have to specify an **owning side** and an **inverse side**. As Doctrine 2 documentation:

- The **inverse side** has to use the mappedBy attribute of the OneToOne,
  OneToMany, or ManyToMany mapping declaration
- The **owning side** has to use the inversedBy attribute of the OneToOne,
  ManyToOne, or ManyToMany mapping declaration
- ManyToOne is always the **owning side** and OneToMany is always the
  **inverse side**

So i messed up with your association in my first answer. In your case `Profile` has to be the inverse side while study should be the owning side. But you are working on `Profile`, so you need the `cascade` annotation on profile to persist new entities:

```
class Profile
{
    /**
     * Bidirectional (INVERSE SIDE)
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Study", mappedBy="profile",
     *     cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $studies;
}

class Study
{
    /**
     * Bidirectional (OWNING SIDE - FK)
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Profile", inversedBy="studies")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $profile;
}
```

Note that your example is exactly the same as [that](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) on Doctrine2 documentation.

Comment: @koral sorry i messed up with the owning thing. I'm going to update the answer.

Comment: I managed to tidy the owning thing as you can see :) But the problem still exists

Comment: @koral see my edits. I made a mistake - in you specific case there are some constraints on what should be the owning/inverse side. See my updated answer and let me know (It must work).

Comment: Not working either - still study.profile_id=null. The D2 example looks similar to mine case but it's managed with code not with Sf2 forms. BTW In Study class I changed referenced column: * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE", referencedColumnName="profile_id")

Answer (score 1):

You have to set profile to instance. In controller. You havent pasted controller code..
You should iterate over $profile->getStudy  collection and set for each item  ->setProfile=$profile.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-1-dynamic-attributes

What is happening there doesnt apply to forms..He actually has a this reference..Hm maybe adding this is a kind of auto fix to avoid iteration, not sure whether it works, i'll try

Comment: @Parths based on example I added method Profile::addStudy() but it's never called. Should be activated somehow?

Comment: as i told you , you should paste the controller code.. You havent show us the controller code..It isnt called automatically!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution did not work for me. In fact I had already set up the relationship and defined the adder, remover, getter and after I saw your solution i added the setter.

However my setter was not called when the form was submitted.

The solution for me was another one.

In the adder method I added a call to set the owner.

```
public function addStudie($studie)
{
     $studie->setProfile($this);
     $this->studies->add($studie);
}
```

And to have this adder called when the form is submitted you need to add to the form collection field the `by_reference` property set to `false`.

```
   $builder->add('study', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new StudyType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                `by_reference` => false,
                'allow_delete' => true
                    )
            )
```

Here is the documentation:

> Similarly, if you're using the CollectionType field where your underlying collection data is an object (like with Doctrine's ArrayCollection), then by_reference must be set to false if you need the adder and remover (e.g. addAuthor() and removeAuthor()) to be called.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference