# symfony2 embedded form won't persist to database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I followed the documentation for this [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html): but could not get the example to persist to the database for the embedded form; the Plant class saved just fine. I am under the assumption that the persist and flush methods in the controller handle the persisting of both entities. Is this wrong to assume?  Do I need to intercept it and set it manually in the controller before flush?

At any rate, here is my code:

```
Plant Entity:

<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Repository\PlantRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="plant")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Plant
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Picture", inversedBy="plants", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="picture")
    */
    protected $pictures;

//...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pictures = new ArrayCollection;
    }

//...

    /**
     * Add pictures
     *
     * @param \Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Picture $pictures
     * @return Plant
     */
    public function addPicture(\Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Picture $pictures)
    {
        $pictures->addPlant($this);
        $this->pictures[] = $pictures;
    }

    /**
     * Remove pictures
     *
     * @param \Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Picture $pictures
     */
    public function removePicture(\Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Picture $pictures)
    {
        $this->pictures->removeElement($pictures);
    }

    /**
     * Get pictures
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getPictures()
    {
        return $this->pictures;
    }
}
```

Picture Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Picture")
 */
class Picture
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;    

//...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    public $path;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Plant", mappedBy="pictures")
     */
    private $plants;


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->plants = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

//...

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return Picture
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * Add plants
     *
     * @param \Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Plant $plants
     * @return Picture
     */
    public function addPlant(\Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Plant $plants)
    {      
        if (!$this->plants->contains($plants)) {
            $this->plants->add($plants);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove plants
     *
     * @param \Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Plant $plants
     */
    public function removePlant(\Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Plant $plants)
    {
        $this->plants->removeElement($plants);
    }

    /**
     * Get plants
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getPlants()
    {
        return $this->plants;
    }
}
```

Plant Form:

```
<?php 

namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PlantForm extends AbstractType
{

    public function __construct($em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

//...

        $builder->add('pictures', 'collection', array(
            'type'      => new PictureForm(),
            'options'   => array(
                'data_class' => 'Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Picture'),
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ));

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Plant',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'plant';
    }
}
```

Picture Form:

```
<?php 

namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PictureForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

//...

        $builder->add('path', 'textarea'); 
//...

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Picture',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'picture';
    }
}
```

Plant Controller:

```
public function newAction(Request $request){   

$plant = new Plant();

$image1 = new Picture();
$plant->getPictures()->add($image1);

$form = $this->createForm(new PlantForm($this->getDoctrine()->getManager()), $plant);

if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($plant);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('route', array(
            'id'    => $plant->getId()  
        )));
    }
}

return $this->render('Bundle:Plant:new.html.twig', array(
'form' => $form->createView()
));

}
```

I suspect I don't have my annotations for the database mapped correctly.  When I open phpadmin, there are no relationships defined in the database.

Comment: add this code after the persisting plant and test it: `$em->persist($image1)`, Maybe it works

Comment: That does work, but I neglected to take $image1 dummy data out (it wasn't supposed to be there in the first place).  Which I have since done, and it now does not persist picture when pictures are dynamically added to the form.  The picture field in plant is actually persisting the ENTIRE plant object... including dynamically added pictures.  Which makes sense.  It's mapped as an array.  What should these fields be mapped as??  Leaving them blank provides an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It was indeed an error with my annotations.  This question was actually answered in a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590159/symfony2-form-and-doctrine2-update-foreign-key-in-assigned-entities-fails-sol).  For my solution, it looked like this:

Plant entity:

```
class Plant
{

//..   

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Picture", inversedBy="plants", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
    */
    protected $pictures;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pictures = new ArrayCollection();
    }   

    public function addPicture(\Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Picture $pictures)
    {
        $pictures->addPlant($this);
        $this->pictures[] = $pictures;
    }   

//..

}

class Picture
{

//..

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Plant", mappedBy="pictures", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $plants;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->plants = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addPlant(\Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Plant $plants)
    {
        if (!$this->plants->contains($plants)) {
            $this->plants->add($plants);
        }
    }   

//..    

}
```

Controller:

public function newAction(Request $request){

```
$plant = new Plant();

if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($plant);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('BloggerBlogBundle_plant_library_show', array(
            'id'    => $plant->getId()  
        )));
    }
}

return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Library:new.html.twig', array(
'form' => $form->createView()
));

}
```

Maybe a useful note to others: this mapping created a new table called plant_picture which holds the association.  I was surprised to learn that a "picture" column was NOT added to the Plant entity at all.